# How can I check and set user status in Rules Action?

Tags: 8, rules

I am using a REST API that creates a user without password. And doing so, the user is successfully created but the status is set to `blocked` - meaning it is not actually logged in.

So im planning to create a custom Rules Action that will set the status into `Active`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is actually a Rules Action that does this functionalities.
I was thinking of a custom Rules Action but glad Drupal 8 Rules supports my use case.